# Iss one intent can have on 50 expressions on wit.ai?

Tags: bots, wit.ai

I have created an application using Wit.ai but when i try to fetch intents from wit . I am getting only 50 intent through API whilte in my wit app i can see more than 50

Comment: You should check the API documentation, maybe there is some sort of limitations, or paging (I have no knowledge of Wit.ai but it's a common practice among APIs to limit or page big results)
If you have taken a look at the API docs and found nothing on why this is happening, state that in your question so people know not to direct you there to look for yourself.